# Mixing fraction notation with slash notation

Tags: notation, article-writing

I am writing a theorem, and in it, I mix $\frac ab$ and $a/b $. The reason for this is that I find

$$\lceil a/b \rceil \tag{1}$$
better-looking than:

$\displaystyle \biggr \lceil \frac ab \biggr \rceil \tag{2}$

or

$\displaystyle \lceil \frac ab \rceil \tag{3}$

or

$$\textstyle \lceil \frac ab \rceil \tag{4}$$

$(2)$ looks weirdly proportioned, and in $(3)$, the ceiling function is too small for the fraction. In $(4)$, the fraction is well-proportioned, but a bit small, making it harder to read. In addition, when used with $\displaystyle \frac ab$, it will lead to differing sizes of the terms, which lookes a bit weird to me. Example: $\displaystyle \frac ab - \textstyle \lceil \frac ab \rceil$.

However, I find $\frac ab$ better-looking than $a/b$, and also easier to read, as I'm not too used to using and reading the slash as a divider. This leads me to mix the two types of dividers. Whenever there's a ceiling/floor function involved, I use the slash, and when there's not, I use the fraction. So my question is, is this common and accepted? Using the $\div$ is apparently not common and "accepted", and since there seems to be a consensus on that, I suspect there may be a consensus on mixing types of notation. If there isn't a consensus, then this question does not have an objective answer other than "there is no consensus" or "there is no consensus, but the majority of papers (...)". If that's the case, I'll accept the answer.

**EDIT:** The context is me writing an applied math paper (applied to the field of organic chemistry). It involves combinatorics and number theory.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid and motivated question and I am sorry to see that it is being downvoted.

Comment: There's also $\lceil \tfrac ab \rceil$ ?   But I am not aware of any "standard" authors are expected to use.

Comment: @amWhy Yeah that's true. It's a bit small however, and it will cause a difference in sizing when used inside display style math, since it is smaller. I'll add it to the list though, as it is an option.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen Thank you. Do you have any ideas as to why it is being downvoted?

Comment: No I don't, but seeing that you raised that question on Meta, I hope you get an explanation there.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen Alright, I hope so too.

Comment: One thing (that some could see as a problem in the question) is that it is *tempting* to answer it by opinions, because that would be easy, while it would take considerable work to answer it by actually looking up style references or observing what is objectively common or not. So it is easy to dismiss the question as "opinion-based".

Comment: @JukkaKohonen That's what I was thinking about as well. However, I also think that even though a question invites a non-objective answer whilst also requiring a lot of work to answer objectively, it shouldn't be downvoted  (or closed, as has been done now). Maybe I am wrong on this, and it is in fact written in the rules that question cannot do this?

Comment: I guess that the downvotes and close votes were because it's more about typography than actual math. But I don't know of any better place for questions about *mathematical typography*.

Comment: It *might* have been better received on MathOverflow, seeing (after edit) that the question is about publishing in applied math. Generally MO is rather welcoming to questions that concern research mathematicians. At least MO has a tag [notation] for such very issues.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen. The tag [notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notation) obviously exists here too.

Comment: md2perpe, yes it does; I mentioned its existence on MO in order to explain that *MO* does not shun on questions of notation.

Comment: @md2perpe There is also [tex.se]...

Comment: @XanderHenderson. Yes, but I do not see that this question fits there. This is not a question about how to accomplish something in (La)TeX.

Comment: @md2perpe You commented about mathematical typography.  While I hate to assume that the existence of a tag implies that questions in that tag are on topic, TeX.se does have a [typography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography) tag which appears to be active.  From the tag wiki there "Questions tagged typography deal with ... and, incidentally, questions about what constitutes good typography in the first place."

Comment: I think this is fine as a question under the article-writing tag. I don't think there is any agreed convention about $a / b$ versus $\frac{a}{b}$, but I would not use $a \div b$ without some very good reason. A convention that I often follow and seems to work well with many of the styles that journals impose is to use $a/b$ in formulas in running texts and $$\frac{a}{b}$$ in displayed formulas. You should certainly use \left\lceil and \right\rceil to get the right size of ceiling symbols $$\left\lceil \frac{a}{b}\right\rceil \quad\mbox{not}\quad \lceil\frac{a}{b}\rceil$$.

Comment: Most helpful comment yet, @RobArthan.  That certainly beats the OP's (2).  I'd encourage you to write an answer with that, which seems to be exactly what the OP would like.

Comment: But note: it looks strange in combination: Even if you think $$\left\lceil \frac{a}{b}\right\rceil \ge \frac{a}{b}$$ is ugly, it is less ugly than $$\left\lceil a/b\right\rceil \ge \frac{a}{b}.$$

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to just trawl through the journal(s) you are planning to publish in, and see what other authors do? There might be some standard they all use (intentionally or not). For instance, on SE, isolated numbers are usually written in latex, but this isn't a rule, just an unspoken convention.

Comment: Maybe if you don't get a definitive answer, try academiaSE or better yet Math Overflow

Comment: IMO $\dfrac ab\ \sqrt{\dfrac ab}\ \left\lceil\dfrac ab\right\rceil$ are harmonious.

Comment: @RobArthan it's better not to use `\left` and `\right` but rather to size manually with e.g. `\Bigl` and `\Bigr`. This is both because `\left`/`\right` often don't give the optimal size, and because they get the horizontal spacing wrong. But that is a topic for tex.stachexchange...

Comment: @EspeciallyLime, They both size to fit what's enclosed: `$\left(\frac 34\right)$ vs. $\Bigl(\frac 34 \Bigr)$`  $\left(\frac 34\right)$ vs. $\Bigl(\frac 34 \Bigr)$.

Comment: @amWhy try it again in display style. `\Bigl` is a fixed size, and you can try other sizes with `\bigl`, `\biggl` or `\Biggl`, and pick the most appropriate. `\left` picks one for you, and it tends to err on the side of being too big. For inline fractions, compare $(\frac 34)$ (nothing), $\bigl(\frac34\bigr)$ (big), $\left(\frac 34\right)$ (left/right). I prefer the middle option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per Section 13.10 of the [AMS Style Guide](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/AMS-StyleGuide-online.pdf):

> Fractions in text may be case (stacked) or slashed.

and

> Fractions need not be consistent (either case or slashed) throughout a
> paper, just within a math phrase.

So while I'm not sure there's any convention specifically for fractions within a floor/ceiling, generally speaking you're free to typeset fractions either way, to maximize legibility and tidiness of the expression, on a case-by-case basis.